# are cranial measurements discrete or continuous data?

Tags: dataset, continuous-data, discrete-data, measurement

I have to find which formula to use to calculate if there is an outlier in this piece of data. They are cranial measurements (Cranial length, Cranial height, Cranial Breadth and Facial Projection Length) which consist of whole numbers like (170mm,180mm,173mm) etc. I am not sure if this is an example of discrete data or continuous. I know discrete is like 24 students and continuous is like 6.5, 6.6 etc. but i know that continuous is a measurement of something which is confusing me because mm is a measurement but all the numbers are whole numbers. Can someone please help me?

Comment: This is clearly measurement data, which probably is rounded to closest integer.

Comment: okay so then it is continuous?

Comment: yes. yes ........................

Comment: I would be very leery of any formula to tell if there are outliers.

Comment: *Data* are neither discrete nor continuous: only our models of them can have those properties.  Think about your implicit model: if the crania were that of standardized robots, then conceivably they would have only a small number of possible values of each factor.  But do you suppose people could possibly be constructed in such a regimented, engineered way?  Of course not.  So the decision you have to make concerns whether it might be worthwhile to model measurements *which have been rounded to the nearest whole value* as discrete or not. That's unlikely to affect how you identify outliers.

Answer (score 1):

Cranial measurements are continuous data. It is round because you are measuring it in mm, imagine you measure it in cm, then you would have decimals.
It would be discrete if you classify it into catergories for example, but given your example, your raw data is continuous.